# Calendar issue in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the Following jquery function for highlight the date in calendar.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
                  time: '2014-10',
                  events: {
                      "2014-10-10": { "number": 5, "url": "http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider" }                
                  }
              });
          });
        </script>
```

If I use like this,I can achieve to highlight the 2014-10-10 date by using

```
"2014-10-10": { "number": 5, "url": "http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider" }
```

But i cant able to highlight When I get the date String in one variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var appointment = "2014-10-10"; 
        var str = '{"' + appointment + '":{"badgeClass":"badge-warning"}}';
        var test2 = JSON.parse(str);

        /* Initialize calendar */
        $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
            time: '2014-10',
            events: { "'+test2+'": { "number": 5, "url": "http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider" } }

            });
    });

   </script>
```

How to highlight date by getting date string in one variable?

Comment: The object that you create in the second example is not the same as in first example. `events: { "'+test2+'"` test2 here is not a string, like the rest in that part of the code. You have to create the whole string as you've done with `str`, parse it into object and set `events` equal to it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

```
$(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
        time: '2014-10',
        events: { test2: { "number": 5, "url": "http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider" } }

        });
```

You have given extra quotes due to which it is considered as variable.

Comment: Also i think you do not need to parse str in JSON.